# Is there a way for app actions to generate a url?

Tags: actions-on-google, deep-linking

I am building a custom intent that will return a recipe if given the name of the food. For example if a user were to say "Hey Google, show me the recipe of banana nut bread on exampleApp" it would pull up that page. The issue is that on the back end, the banana nut bread recipe is associated with an number. So the url will be something like "https://exampleapp.com/4". Is there a way for my app action to call a function that returns the correct url?

Answer (score 0):

You can support this by adding an intent parameter to your custom intent for the food name.

The key of each food name can be the id/number, and you can add synonyms for real words like 'banana bread'.

When the intent is triggered, you can resolve the intent parameter to use the key (id/number) rather than whatever the user said ('banana bread'), and form the URL from this.